# Superclass returning a subclass type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider the following scenario very common in OO literature:

```
public class Vehicle {
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
}

public class Bike extends Vehicle {
}
```

Now, suppose I want to create a function `get()` that will always return the subclass type so I could get a subclass instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car car = Car.get();
    Bike bike = Bike.get();
    car.Start();
    bike.Start();
}
```

It is possible to implement a `public static <T> T get()` in the superclass that is aware of its return type without passing it as a parameter or casting from a `Object`?

**UPDATE:**

In the first version I was talking about abstract class. Now I removed the abstract and I'm using a regular class.

Comment: I wonder if Java supports the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: why would you want to do that the whole point of an abstract class is to hide concrete details.

Comment: Why don't you just say : `Vehicle car = new Car();` ....and so on ?

Comment: No it isn't. Java doesn't have static abstract methods.

Comment: Why does it have to be on the abstract class? It will only be called for the subclasses, so just define two static methods in the subclasses. By chance they have the same name ...

Comment: Maybe my choice of using an abstract class was wrong. Indeed abstract classes hide concrete details, but in my case I would like to keep an implementation in a single place as all subclasses will use the very same function.

Comment: Just updated my question.

@KuraFaqir As I said, this get() will do a lot of processing, so I would like to have a generic object factory as all my classes will be derived from the same superclass.

Comment: Because of type erasure, you cannot know at run time the actual type to which T is bound in the calling code without passing a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, Java does not know which type of subclass you would like to return if you call a static method on a superclass. You mentioned that you would like to do it without passing in a parameter, you can't. If you can pass in a parameter, this is how you would do it:

```
package com.stackexchange.stackoverflow;

public class Question19281170 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Car car = Vehicle.get(Car.class);
    Bike bike = Bike.get(Bike.class);
    car.start();
    bike.start();
  }

  static abstract class Vehicle {
    public void start() {
      System.out.println(String.format("Start %s", toString()));
    }
    public static <T extends Vehicle> T get(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
      return clazz.newInstance();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Vehicle";
    }
  }

  static class Car extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Car";
    }
  }

  static class Bike extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Bike";
    }
  }
}
```

The best practice for this would be to just use polymorphism:

```
Vehicle car = new Car();
Vehicle bike = new Bike();
```

Comment: The code in `main` could just as well be `Bike bike = Vehicle.get(Bike.class)`.

Comment: Yes, this is illustrated on the previous line: Car car = Vehicle.get(Car.class); I just wanted to demonstrate both methods. In fact, if passing a parameter is an okay solution, the generics could be removed from the superclass, and a simple Utility class with any generic get method could be used. It seems pointless though.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is a powerful feature and well-suited to the construction of class-based hierarchies such as the one found in JavaFX.

But designing classes for inheritance is a pain and fraught with potential problems.  Here's a common problem: what if you decide that you want to use a HashMap to represent a collection of Vehicles?  The problem is that writing equals() and hashcode() methods for subclasses in a way that doesn't break the contracts for equals() and hashcode() is harder than it sounds.  Moreover, inheritance breaks encapsulation and makes your subclasses dependent upon the implementation details in the superclass which can make your code fragile or more difficult to maintain.

An alternative to inheritance is to use an interface-based type system, similar to that which is used by the Java Collections API.

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public void start();
    :
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
}

public class Bike implements Vehicle {
}
```

The interface functions as the base type, which has several advantages.  Foremost is that any class that implements the Vehicle interface can be passed to any method that asks for a Vehicle, no matter what the class is.  Although this appears similar to inheritance, there is no actual class-based hierarchy.  All the problems with implementation details, encapsulation, and equals() contracts go away.

The downsides to an interface-based type system are several:

- You have to be able to robustly specify the behavior of your base type with the interface definition.  Absent this, the interface as a base type becomes inconvenient.
- Interfaces have to be fully implemented by each class the uses it (unless you create an abstract skeletal implementation class for your interface, eg. AbstractList in the Collections API).
- It is hard to change interfaces ... but it is often problematic to edit superclasses.  Remember that changes to the superclass can create side-effects in their subclasses that are dependent upon the implementation details in the superclass.

Having an interface-based type makes your situation look something like this (static factory is used):

```
Vehicle car = Car.newInstance();
Vehicle bike = Bike.newInstance();

car.start();
bike.start();
```

TL;DR: Interface-based type systems are useful to address the problems of creating a class-based type system (inheritance breaks encapsulation) and can be a good alternative solution for certain problems.